# Android vertical barrier is not aligning

Tags: android, barrier

I am having trouble to aligning `TextView`s and `Barrier` in Android. Somehow the barrier stays/stick to the left or right edge of the parent layout. See the blue and green line in image.

I want to align the barrier in the way the red line in image so it can separate left and right content.

[image]

## Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover_photo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ferrari"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_avatar"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/user_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Lora Mitchell's Car"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/manufacturer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Manufacturer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/model"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Model"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/manufacturer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Type"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/model" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bore_stroke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Bore and stroke"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/type" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/max_power"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Maximum power**"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bore_stroke" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/specific_power"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Specific power output"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/max_power" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/max_torque"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Maximum torque"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/specific_power" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="V8 - 90°"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="351dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="bore_stroke,manufacturer,max_torque,model,max_power,type,specific_power" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that barrier is the best option to separate left and right in your screen, from the documentation :

> If the widgets dimensions change, the barrier will automatically move according to its direction to get the most extreme widget:

In my layouts using constraint layout when I want to separate right and left part of the screen I usually use guideline in this way :

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
android:id="@+id/guideline"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

I constraint all of my views to the guideline and it works like charm.

Comment: I see. But guideline is not the correct way or maybe I don't know how to set and constraint to the left side text to keep the same distance from it. As I have tried guide which always keep constraint to the parent layout. So I am not yet sure to use Guide in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by guidline is not the correct way? What is wrong with it?

Comment: I want the guide or barrier stick with to the right of the title text. Will guide can do that? If than I need to learn how.

Comment: you can do it, for example, put some view and guideline and drag the right side of the view to the left side of the guideline or the other way around, with this your view will stick to the guideline , i hope that this was helpful